What is the point of asking questions here, if you cannot reply to people?
I have used this site for year, but only recently got an account. Which should not be as hard as it was. I was very excited though. What with the world ending and Dead Internet.
But why can we not reply to people on here?

Why do you thing we should be able? It is not social network, it is QA site.
